# Invertible matrix simple problem

Tags: linear-algebra

I am a bit confused here, on the following question.

> Determine whether this statement is true:
>
> If matrix **A** is invertible and **B**≠0, then **AB**≠0

The book says it is true. But I can think about a counterexample:

If **B** has a row of zeros, it satisfies **B**≠0, but on the other hand: det(**B**)=0

Thus: det(**AB**)=det(**A**) ∙ det(**B**)=0

Comment: So what?  The conclusion, at least as you have written it, is NOT that "det(AB) is not 0" but that AB is not 0.

Comment: Seems to be related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459021/prove-that-if-ab-is-invertible-then-b-is-invertible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement says $AB \neq 0$, which is much weaker than saying that $\det(AB) \neq 0$. If $AB = 0$ and $A$ is invertible, we can apply $A^{-1}$ to get $B = 0$, which contradicts $B \neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand it

Comment: If $AB=0$ and $A$ is invertible, multiply with the inverse of $A$ from the left. Then $B=0$ follows